# Как убрать "родной" белый фон иконки, чтобы он не перекрывал фон родительского блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть иконка-домик. Домик черный, на белом фоне - это сама картинка. А родительский блок-контейнер серый:

```
<div class="container" style="background-color:grey;">
  <img src="home.svg">
</div>
```

И в итоге получается белая квадратная картинка с домиком. Как убрать фон самой картинки, чтобы он не светился поверх родительского блока, а отображался только сам домик(его контуры) поверх серого фона? Надеюсь, понятно объяснил...

Comment: Перерисовать изображение с прозрачным фоном?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Откройте `home.svg` в редакторе и поищите элемент, являющийся белым фоном. Искать следует элемент с атрибутом `fill="#ffffff"` или `fill="#fff"` или `fill="white"` или `fill="rgb(255,255,255)"`. Затем, либо удалите этот атрибут, либо добавьте `fill-opacity="0"`.

Если внутри свгшки картинка закодированная в `base64`, то конвертируйте её обратно в png и сотрите фон в каком-нибудь редакторе, позволяющим работать с альфой.

Comment: Я работаю в Incscape. Не подскажете, как там сделать фон прозрачным для svg картинки?

Answer (score 0):

В данный момент у тебя изображение с непрозрачным фоном и формат у него jpg скорее всего. В фотошопе сделай изображению прозрачный фон и сохрани как png. Пример как это делается: https://www.templatemonster.com/help/ru/photoshop-how-to-make-image-transparent.html

Comment: `<img src="home.svg">` - читайте внимательнее.

Comment: Я работаю в Incscape. Не подскажете, как там сдклать фон прозрачным для svg картинки?

Comment: Не работал в этой программе, не могу помочь(

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться свойством `mix-blend-mode` в css

```
.parrent { background: gray; }
.parrent img { mix-blend-mode: multiply; }
```

ну и в html

```
<div class="parrent">
  <img src="..." />
</div>
```